# Добавить к имени файла индекс

Tags: php

Я загружаю файл на сервер через php,

```
 if($_FILES["photo"]["size"] > 1024*3*1024)
   {
     echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
     exit;
   }
   // Проверяем загружен ли файл
   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]))
   {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "photos/".$_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
   } else {
   }
```

Но если у меня в папке photos есть фото с именем 1.jpg и я загружаю фото с именем 1.jpg, второе замещает первое, как сделать так, чтобы если есть фото в папке с таким именем переименовывалось в 1(1).jpg, а если есть 1.jpg и 1(1).jpg, то 1(1)(1).jpg и т.д. Пожалуйста помогите!

Comment: Полностью написать не могу, сам алгоритм должен быть таким:

* Проверяем наличие файла с таким именем. Если такой файл находится:
    * Получаем файлы в папке
    * Выбираем подходящие под шаблон имени текущего
    * Выбираем "максимальное" имя (зависит от способа именования)
    * Вытаскиваем из этого имени индекс и прибавляем единицу (если именуем как photo-N.jpg) / удлиняем имя (если сделать как здесь).
* Пишем файл

Comment: Способ интересный, но думаю гораздо затратнее, чем я предложил. т.к. мутить с шаблонами на ходу это похоже на магию. Проще перебрать и понятнее и по скорости будет быстрее.

А вообще самый логичный для меня вариант мутить не с цифрами, а дописывать таймстемп. т.е. `"1".time().".jpg";`

Comment: @Антон Лакотко, под шаблоном не обязательно имелись в виду регэкспы, можно просто считывать последнее число в имени файла. И если говорить про эффективность - то на больших количествах файлов каждый раз вызывать `file_exists` совсем не ок.

Comment: @Fike Хорошо вот вам папка с загруженными файлами с общим их количеством 1 миллион, где названия совершенно разные от обычных 1.jpg до 3sa!dfsc_ssd3.tar.gz.zip.backub2314~.php.bak_ 
И вот вы считываете всю папку, ищите по шаблону при этом каким-то образом сравниваете строки, чтобы определить максимальное значение.
А как практика показывает, что число повторяющихся файлов  с таким именем 1(1).zip,  1(2).zip,  1(3).zip  не будет превышать даже тысячи. А вот в папках аплоада на практике количество файлов может даже доходить до максимума файловой системы.

Comment: @Антон Лакотко, если у меня миллионы файлов, то я не парюсь и а) делаю cdn с разносом файлов по серверам и б) использую хэш-функцию для создания уникального имени. В этом случае тоже будет угадывание существования через `file_exists`, но в большинстве случаев однократное.

Comment: @Fike поэтому я и говорю, что для меня логичнее мутить не с цифрами, а дописывать, на крайний случай, дату и микровремя. Или как в вашем случае: распределять по серверам и хешировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1(1)(1) -- очень не красиво.

Вот тебе функция. писал без проверки, если что пиши в комменты.

```
function smart_move( $src, $dst ){
    //Getting folder + file_name + extension;
    if ( ! preg_match( '|(.+/)(.+)\.(\w+)$|', $dst, $m ) ){
            //Bad destination path;
            return false;
        }
    $path = $m[1]; $file_name = $m[2]; $extension = $m[3];
    $i = 1; $MAX_I = 999999;
    while ( file_exists( $dst ) && $i < $MAX_I ){
            $dst = $path . $file_name . "($i)" . '.' . $extension;
            $i++;
        }
    if ( $i < $MAX_I ){
            move_uploaded_file($src, $dst); return true;
        } else
    return false;
}
```

Добавь её вызов вместо `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "photos/".$_FILES["photo"]`

Comment: вместо preg_match лучше пользоваться готовыми инструментами: [dirname()][1], [basename()][2], [pathinfo()][3]

 [1]: http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.dirname.php
 [2]: http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php
 [3]: http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php